# Creation of TUN/TAP interface for UDP sniffing

Tags: c, linux, networking, proxy, tap

I am writing a program to proxy UDP packets from incoming traffic on a Linux machine to my program. The goal is to simply print only UDP packets of machines traffic. In order to complete this task I defined separate steps.

1. Create TAP interface
2. Add TAP interface to network bridge
3. Read from TAP interface file descriptor.

But the problem is, I don't understand why after running this function

```
int tun_alloc(char* dev, int flags, const char* ip, int port)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int fd, err;

    const char* clonedev = "/dev/net/tun";

    if( (fd = open(clonedev, O_RDWR)) < 0) 
    {
        perror("Opening /dev/net/tun");
        return fd;
    }

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));

    ifr.ifr_flags = flags | IFF_UP;

    if(*dev)
    {
        strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);
    }

    if((err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("ioctl(TUNSETIFF)");
        close(fd);
        return err;
    }

    strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);
    return fd;
}
```

and invoking ifconfig in another terminal I can't see tap network device ? Why I have to create it before running this function ?